# VisualVM Profiling of JavaFX Application

Tags: javafx, profiling, javafx-8, visualvm

I am trying to CPU profile a JavaFX 8 application with VisualVM (Java 8). While CPU sampling works fine, when starting CPU profiling, the application just hangs and VisualVM reports as status "profiling running (0 methods instrumented)".

I tried to limit profiling to my app´s classes, but to no avail. Am I missing something?

Comment: PS: JDK is 1.8.0 Update 25

Comment: jvisualvm just sucks like that. you need a profiler that can instrument the app using JVM agents that instrument it on startup

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most probably this is caused by lambda expression(s). Currently they are constantly throwing `ClassNotFoundException`s, see the bug report over here: https://java.net/jira/browse/VISUALVM-601

Updated: With the Version 1.3.9 this issue has been resolved.

Comment: It's nice to see they are at least aware of this problem, although I don't understand why it wasn't fixed yet, seeing as presumably the same problem _was_ fixed in NetBeans, bu the same person assigned to this bug in VisualVM. However, this doesn't really help me use VisualVM to profile JavaFX applications...

Comment: @sillyfly If the same bug occurs in your application: You won't be able to use it with VisualVM until it is fixed..

Comment: It happens in _every_ JavaFX application, regardless of my own code.

Comment: That is most probably because of the JDK using lambdas too.. Did you take a look at the log files?

Comment: Yes, the lambdas seem to be coming from within the JDK, which is perfectly fine and normal.  
Here's an example of the exceptions I'm swamped with: Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/javafx/tk/Toolkit$$Lambda$163

Comment: I guess. What is the common SE etiquette about bounties in this case? Am I expected to award the bounty for a "there's no answer" answer? Or is the bounty to be un-awarded?

Comment: Good one. I really don't know. This here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer states: "[..]It simply means that the author received an answer that worked for him or her personally[..]

Comment: Well... it didn't. Not really, as it doesn't solve the problem. It only tells me there currently _can't be_ a solution. Still, I guess the points will go to waste otherwise, so I'll award to bounty, mostly for saving me from working hard to try more ways of solving it.

Comment: I am sorry, but I have not found any other solution. I just use a different profiler for JavaFX applications (if you are interested: do a quick google search (it starts with "your" and ends with "kit")).